# Getting Type of Type Parameter in Instantiated Object

Tags: scala

Given a `trait` with a Type Member:

```
trait Bippy {
 type A 
}

object BippyImpl extends Bippy { override type A = Int }
```

I can use `A`'s type of `BippyImpl`:

```
scala> val x: BippyImpl.A = 42
x: BippyImpl.A = 42
```

And then, given a `trait` with a Type Parameter:

`trait Foo[A]`

I can define an instance via:

`object FooImpl extends Foo[Int]`

But, how can I get access to `Foo`'s type from `FooImpl`?

Comment: I'm confused. You know that the type is `Int` because you wrote `extends Foo[Int]`. What do you mean by "get access" to it?

Comment: If you simply want to create an alias you can do `trait Foo[A] { type B = A }`, `val x: FooImpl.B = 1`